# How to add a style to a <g> within an existing <svg>

Tags: svg.js

I have 3 identical SVGs displaying on my page. But they are placed dynamically (I'm using WordPress, with a plugin that inlines all SVG images). I'm using them to show percentages of different categories by adding a linear gradient. But each image needs to have a different linear gradient definition and fill url.
So what I'm trying to figure out is whether I can use **svg.js** to just insert those defs & styles on the fly, based on the unique `div` `id` that each svg is inside of, or whether I need to use it to generate the entire SVGs themselves (I would rather not do this, since I need to make a lot of this easily changeable on the fly, through the administrative backend of the site).

Comment: Sure. You can grab any dom element via `SVG('css selector')` and then do stuff with it. e.g. adding devs or style: `SVG('#id').defs().rect(100, 100)`

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to find some examples of the script written out in order to wrap my head around it. Individual lines of what could work are just making my brain shut down at the moment. HAHA. I appreciate knowing that this *can* work though! Much appreciated!